# How to check httponly cookie exists in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, httponly

I want to check if an httponly cookie(ex.accessToken) exists.

This is because I want to write logic based on the existence of cookies.

Comment: Send a request to your back end, and if it comes back with 401 you can assume you have a missing or expired access token. Also as a side note, be aware that storing an access token in a cookie may make you vulnerable to CSRF attacks unless you take additional precautions such as adding an anti-CSRF token.

Comment: Thanks to you I was able to solve it!